# Why was the epithet varAha (वराह) used for Rudra in Rig Veda I.114.5?

Tags: vishnu, rig-veda, varaha, rudra

Rig Veda I.114.5 (dedicated to **Rudra**) says

> दि॒वो **व॑रा॒ह**म॑रु॒षं क॑प॒र्दिनं॑ त्वे॒षं रू॒पं नम॑सा॒ नि ह्व॑यामहे
> । हस्ते॒ बिभ्र॑द् भेष॒जा वार्या॑णि॒ शर्म॒ वर्म॑ च्छ॒र्दिर॒स्मभ्यं॑
> यंसत् ॥५॥
>
> We call down with reverence the ***boar of*** heaven, flame-red, with
> braided hair, turbulent in form. Bearing in his hand desirable healing
> remedies, he will extend shelter, covering, and protection to us.

In Puranas it was used to indicate the incarnation of Vishnu.

My question is - Why was the epithet varAha (वराह) used for Rudra in Rig Veda I.114.5?

**Edit 31-8-2020**

In the mantra व॑रा॒हम॑रु॒षं Can be split into varAham + aruSa . aruSa indicates ***shape of a varAha***.

Comment: @PrasannaR: If varAha means sky, then are there varAha for heaven, as mentioned in the mantra - दि॒वो, and varAha for Earth, ie., sky for Earth?  If so, what is the reference for that usage?

Comment: @PrasannaR: Still not clear as to what you are hinting at.  Can you post an answer, explaining in detail?

Comment: Why do you post lengthy comments, which are not understandable to ordinary people like me? :-) Please write an answer @PrasannaR

Answer (score 5):

Varaha is interpreted as strength of a boar in this verse by the commentator Sayana. Rudra does not become a Varaha but is as strong as a Varaha.

> Sayana: firm limbs like a Varaha.

Rig Veda Samhita 1.114.5, Bengali translation by Nilanjana Sikdardutta, Ramakrishna Mission Institute of Culture

Comment: In their translations **Stephanie W. Jamison and Joel P. Brereton** and **Ralph T.H. Griffith** mentioned varAha as boar.

Comment: The word Varaha is used to signify the strength of a boar and not boar itself. At least that is how Sayana understands it. I have edited my post to make this point clear.

Comment: There were criticisms on Sayana's work as Puranic based, lacking depth, etc, especially from Sri Aurobindo and others.  So is the translation of Sayana dependable?  Further, Sayana might not have translated varAha as boar, because it comes in the way of Vishnu's incarnation.

Comment: Yes, Sayana's commentary has been questioned. However, here it seems to me that Sayana could well be right since he is saying Varaha should be understood as conveying strength. So this interpretation sidesteps the objection that Varaha is Vishnu's incarnation since he is not saying that Rudra is a Varaha.

Comment: I have my own apprehension on this translation.   Thanks for responding.

Comment: In the mantra व॑रा॒हम॑रु॒षं Can be split into varAham + aruSa .  aruSa indicates shape of a varAha.  Hence, Sayana definitely went wrong here.

Comment: "There were criticisms on Sayana's work as Puranic based" - The Vedas are supposed to be interpreted based on the Puranas and Smritis, since the Vedic sentences are ambiguous. Moreover, it is better to rely on the commentaries of orthodox Vedic scholars rather than neoHindus (aurobindo) and atheists (Western indologists). Secondly aruSa also means "reddish" so it can mean "like a red boar".

Comment: Why for strength Varaha is chosen.. why not narasimha for any other creation of vishnu or for that mater hanuman is well know for strength or animal wise also Strength is elephant.. or lion. not anothre createure comes to mind for strength. @PradipGangopadhyay so logic of strength is wrong.. Varaha means rain bearing cloud that is the meaning in ancient sanskirt.. may sanaya wrote after 1500 AD i dont know because even 1000 AD abinahv kosha sanskrit mentions rain bearing cloud.factually wrong interpretation by sayanaacharya..

Answer (score 0):

> In Puranas it was used to indicate the incarnation of Vishnu.

Not only in the Puranas but in the Vedas too Varaha is mentioned as an incarnation of Vishnu.

From the Mahanarayana Upanishad of the Krishna Yajur Veda:

> uddhrtAsi varAheNa krishNena shatabAhunA

> You (mother Earth) were lifted up by Krishna (Vishnu) with his hundred arms in the form of Varaha.

So this is not a "puranic concept" as you might think.

As for your main question, the translation you provided says this:

> We call down with reverence the boar of heaven...

This just looks like a metaphorical description of Shiva as the might of heaven, comparing him to the might of a boar.

Comment: It is not Shiva that was referred to in the mantra of Rig Veda , but Rudra.  Further, can you explain what is the metaphorical description of Rudra as the might of heaven?

Comment: @SrimannarayanaKV Shiva and Rudra are the same person, different names. This is accepted by all orthodox Shaiva sects too. "The might of heaven" means that he protects heaven from Asuras, etc. After all, he destroyed tripura.

Comment: Sorry. Don't mix up Rig Veda and Puranas.  If you know an answer please update

Comment: I'm curious, how come you think Shiva and Rudra are different beings?

Comment: Because it was clearly told that Rudra is grandson Narayana and son of brahma.. Shiva name is not mentioned inorder escape that they treat this as 2 different entity.. but suprising advaita should add more confusion into this. thinking of themselves as these 2.

Comment: @Srimannarayana KV. According to you, and your understanding of scriptures, do you think there exist sada shiva different from rudra (samhAra karta)? Or else do you think there is no such sada shiva in rig veda?

Comment: @Satya: With my limited knowledge, even if I say something, the majority of members will get furious and start calling me names.  I had posted a question, and if you know the answer , please post it.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/30086)

Comment: @sv. The last sentence in this answer is answering the question.

Comment: I can't really tell, you should probably begin your answer with that and move the other commentary to the end.

Comment: @sv. First one should remove false suppositions, and then give the correct answer.

Comment: Only one line of the answer is actually answering the question. It would be more useful if it's elaborated with some citation